# How do I create a data-driven SSRS subscription from a SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, subscription, data-driven

I am trying to set up a data driven subscription to an SSRS report. I'd like to use a sharepoint list that contains the recipient email address and a report parameter that will filter the contents of the report differently for each recipient.

Microsoft SharePoint List is one of the options in the create data-driven subscription wizard (SSRS 2008 R2) but none of the tutorials I can find on the interwebs describe how to configure the connection string and formulate the query to return the contents of the list. Everything I can find on created data-driven subscriptions uses connections to Sql Server databases to drive the delivery and configuration. I'd rather use a sharepoint list as it seems like an easy way to manage the recipients.

Anybody done this or have a good link to examples of how to configure this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633650.aspx

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is the same connection string you'd use to connect an SSRS report to a sharepoint list.  It should look like this  http://{sharepointDomain}/{YourSite}.

As for the query, it should look something like this--I got this by using the query designer in SSRS.  I find that using the query designer to stub out my query is best--then if you need to add filters or anything you may add more syntax to the optional  tags.

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>MyList</ListName>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="name" />
    <FieldRef Name="email" />
  </ViewFields>
  <Query> --if you have any filters, put them in this section here, otherwise remove the Query tags
  </Query>
</RSSharePointList>
```

Here's an article I wrote giving a step-by-step guide to setting it up.

http://jaysonseaverbi.blogspot.com/2013/11/data-driven-subscription-using.html